# Possible confusion while computing Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Suppose that $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ is $1-$periodic and of class $C^k$. Show that $n ^k \hat{f} (n)$ goes to $0$ as $\rvert n \lvert \to \infty$.

By integrating by parts $k$ times, I have that $$\hat f(n)=\frac{1}{2 \pi in^k} \int_0^1f^{(k)}(x)e^{-2 \pi inx}dx$$

Since $f^{(k)}(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $\exists M$ such that $\lvert f^{(k)}(x)\rvert \leq M$ but since $\int_0^1e^{-2 \pi inx}dx=0$ this gives me that $$\lvert n^k\hat{f}(n) \rvert \leq \frac{M}{2 \pi } \lvert \int_0^1e^{-2 \pi inx}dx \rvert=0$$ and it means that $n^k\hat{f}(n)=0$. I am surely making a mistake here but I cannot find it. I am also thinking about the fact that $f$ and its derivatives are $1-$periodic, $e^{-2 \pi inx}$ too, so their product also $1-$periodic and the integral between $0$ and $1$ must be $0$ so $\hat f(n)=0$ which seems absurd. Does someone see what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You incorrectly exchanged abosolute value and integral. It should be $$\left|\int_0^1 f^{(k)}(x)e^{-2i\pi nx}dx\right| \leq \int_0^1 \left| f^{(k)}(x)e^{-2i\pi nx}\right|dx\leq M$$

Comment: Okay and what about the 2nd argument ?

Comment: Why do you think that the integral of a periodic function is always zero?

Comment: @StefanLafon Nevermind lol, thanks